# Animate scroll to hash inside div not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, jquery-animate

Why is this working only when the scrolling is of the page itself but not within a div? I does move to the right location only without the animation.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash;
    var $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 5000, function () {
      window.location.hash = target;
    });
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/ilyador/pen/OPpWKd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the animate to the wrap class like this update of your pen 
[>> codePen  <<](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emvvNd) 
 changed to

```
 $('.wrap').stop().animate({
```